# Restrict querying by a certain child value in security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm struggling to come up with the best way to structure part of my database and its associated security rules.

I have chat groups, and users can be added to those groups at any point. When users are added to a group, they should be able to retrieve only the messages sent *after* that. It shouldn't be possible for them to retrieve any messages that were sent before they (the users) were added to the group.

My first approach wrongly assumed that security rules would apply only to the data being queried.

Simplifying it for this question, I had the following structure:

```js
{
    "groups": {
        "-Kb9fw20GqapLm_b8JNE": {
            "name": "Cool people"
        }
    },
    "groupUsers": {
        "-Kb9fw20GqapLm_b8JNE": {
            "3JzxHLv4b6TcUBvFL64Tyt8dTXJ2": {
                "timeAdded": 1230779183745
            },
            "S2GMKFPOhVhzZL7q4xAVFIHTmRC3": {
                "timeAdded": 1480113719485
            }
        }
    },
    "groupMessages": {
        "-Kb9fw20GqapLm_b8JNE": {
            "-KbKWHv4J4XN22aLMzVa": {
                "from": "3JzxHLv4b6TcUBvFL64Tyt8dTXJ2",
                "text": "Hello",
                "timeSent": "1358491277463"
            },
            "-KfHxtwef6_S9C5huGLI": {
                "from": "S2GMKFPOhVhzZL7q4xAVFIHTmRC3",
                "text": "Goodbye",
                "timeSent": "1493948817230"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And these security rules:

```js
{
    "rules": {
        "groupMessages": {
            ".indexOn": "timeSent",
            "$groupKey": {
                ".read": "root.child('groupUsers').child(auth.uid).child($groupKey).child('timeAdded').val() <= data.child('timeSent').val()"
                ".write": "!data.exists() && root.child('groupUsers').child(auth.uid).child($groupKey).exists() && newData.child('from').val() === auth.uid",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that, I figured I could retrieve the messages for a particular group like so:

```js
var myTimeAdded = /* already retrieved from the database */;
firebase.database()
  .ref('groupMessages/-Kb9fw20GqapLm_b8JNE')
  .orderByChild('timeSent')
  .startAt(myTimeAdded)
  .on('child_added', /* ... */);
```

But like I said, that was a wrong assumption. Any suggestion on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read rules are enforced at the location where you attach a listener.

So in your case that is `groupMessages/-Kb9fw20GqapLm_b8JNE`. If your user has read permission there the listener is allowed. If the user does not have read permission, the listener is rejected/cancelled.

This means that rules cannot be used to filter data. We often refer to this as "rules are not filters" and it's one of the most common pitfalls for developers who are new to Firebase's security model. See:

- the section [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the Firebase documentation
- previous [questions about Firebase that mention "rules are not filters"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters)

By themselves your rules are not wrong: they only allow access to each specific child if it's not too old. They just don't allow you to run a query on `groupMessages/-Kb9fw20GqapLm_b8JNE` anymore.

The common way to work around this is to have a separate structure (commonly called an "index") with *the keys of the items* that your query would otherwise return. In your case it looks like that might turn into a index for each user with the keys of all messages after they joined.

But I'll be honest, it sounds like you're trying to use security rules in a SQL way here. It seems unlikely that the user isn't *allowed* to see older messages. More likely is that you don't want the user to be bother by the older messages. In that case, I'd just solve it with a query (as you already have) and remove the `".read"` rule.

Comment: Yup, I figured so after reading the docs. I couldn't seem to find any alternative approach after some googling around so I thought I should ask. Any suggestions? Could you point me towards any resources I could read to shed some light? Thanks for answering anyway :)

Comment: Yup, I got distracted. Added more info now.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

I thought about the "index" earlier but I was trying to avoid doing that, although It seems like the best solution. I could have a function triggered with every new message that copies the message key to a separate structure for every user currently in the group. My main concern with this approach is that messages sent in quick succession could temporarily appear out of order since functions aren't always run in the same order as they are triggered.

I wish not limiting what messages can be retrieved based on the date was an option, but it's not in this particular app