# Read Dynamically created child with rules imposed in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have child records which are dynamically created based on `auth.uid`

```
{
  "map" : {
    "bpudzUe0maQYxk3cPETeTvy7MAt2" : {
      "latitude" : 28.63,
      "longitude" : 77.375,
      "timestamp" : 1490448969248,
    },
    "geQ0l71zJxgwgbwr3lAb8ScER8O2" : {
      "latitude" : 28.62965996,
      "longitude" : 77.375434,
      "timestamp" : 1490450348739,
    }
  }
}
```

I have rules that I want to read all child records that are created within 15 minutes -

```
{
  "rules": {
    "map": {
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "$id":{
      ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 900000)"
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I am trying to read the messages -

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
database.getReference("map").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

But it always prompts the message `Permission Denied`.

**UPDATE**
I changed rule to -

```
{
  "rules": {
    "map": {
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$id":{
      ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 900000)"
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Now I could read the records but it is showing me all of them and not the latest ones.

Comment: Firebase Database read rules are enforced when you attach a listener. If you have permission at *the location* that you attach a listener to, the read is allowed. If you don't have permission at the location, the listener is rejected. That means that these rules can never be used to filter data. See my most recent answer to a question this, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982668/restrict-querying-by-a-certain-child-value-in-security-rules/42982770#42982770

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In Firebase documentation there is line -        ` `".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)",`. I guess I am trying to achieve the same thing ?

Comment: That sample allows that node to be read if the data in it no older than 1 minute. It does not allow querying the node above it. I agree that it might be a confusing sample without that context.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry to bother you again, I updated my question. Now parent has the read permission but now I am seeing all the records instead of ones which are only 15 minutes older.

Comment: Rules cannot be used to filter data. Please read the question I linked you to and the links I provided there.